# Rails and simple form: novalidate attribute doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, simple-form

my login page( build with simple form) add by default html attributes for browser validation on email input that chrome doesn't recognize and show "Please match the requested format."

Maybe is Chrome bug(on firefox works), so have tried to disable browser validation with simple form config 
`SimpleForm.html5` and `SimpleForm.browser_validations`(false by default), restarted rails but remain the same input:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" class="string email optional form-control
input-xlarge" id="customer_email" maxlength="255"
name="customer[email]" pattern="\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z"
size="255" type="email">
```

have tried also to add on form `html: {novalidate: true}`, same output

finally have tried to add on input_filed `:novalidate => true`, the html output change to:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" class="string email optional form-control
input-xlarge" id="customer_email" maxlength="255"
name="customer[email]" pattern="\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z"
size="255" type="email" novalidate="novalidate">
```

but browser validation and chrome error is present.

Any idea to resolve?

PS: Use Bootstrap and the login form is from Devise resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the pattern attribute from the input element that is causing a problem. You just need to set `pattern: false` on the input field.

So your input field might look something like this:

```
<%= f.input_field :email, type: 'email', required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', pattern: false %>
```

(`nil` doesn't work; it has to be `false`.)

This worked for me in Rails 4.